# Troublesome filter behavior when implementing the "Sieve of Eratosthenes" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, primes

I came up with this Python code for the *trial division* variant of the ["Sieve of Eratosthenes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes):

```
import itertools

def sieve():
    # begin with all natural numbers above 1
    picker = itertools.count(2)
    while True:
        # take the next available number
        v = next(picker)
        yield v
        # filter from the generator its multiples
        picker = filter(lambda x: x % v != 0, picker)
```

It doesn't work as I expected.

When debugging it I get some behavior I don't understand when `filter` gets called: the `x` parameter of the lambda gets a concrete argument which is the next element from the `picker` generator. I don't understand this behavior not even after looking at the documentation of `filter`.

Running

```
s = sieve()
for i in range(5):
    print(next(s))
```

I get:

```
2
3
4
5
6
```

Instead of

```
2
3
5
7
11
```

**UPDATE:**

My bug comes from a misunderstanding of how lambdas work in Python, more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture).

Adding an extra parameter to the lambda fixes the issue:

```
picker = filter(lambda x, prime = v: x % prime != 0, picker)
```

Comment: `filter` works on finite "lists", and `itertools.count()` is an infinite iterator.. that line will never finish.  Maybe you meant `itertools.ifilter(..)`?

Comment: @thebjorn That's not quite the correct explanation for why it doesn't work. If the `filter` line would take forever, the loop would hang. But the loop runs fine, it only produces the wrong values.

Comment: @thebjorn I don't agree with that.

The documentation[1] states it works on iterables, and the definition of iterbales[2] states nothing about their finite property. The filter call also returns and produces a filter object, with some unexpected(by me) contents.

[1]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter
[2]: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is because you rely on local variables and the generators you create (using `filter()`) are referencing the local variables which are overwritten when the generator goes on iterating.

If you use a local function instead, it works fine:

```
def sieve():
    def selector(iterator, d):
        for x in iterator:
            if x % d != 0:
                yield x
    picker = itertools.count(2)
    while True:
        # take the next available number
        prime = next(picker)
        yield prime
        # filter from the generator its multiples
        picker = selector(picker, prime)
```

Trying `list(itertools.islice(sieve(), 10))` shows:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

But I really need to point out that this is a purely educational solution to show how things work.  I would not propose to use this solution for any productive code.  It builds up a large amount of generators internally which are freed only when you drop the handle of the parent generator.  This is probably a waste of resources and you can create an infinite amount of prime numbers without creating an infinite amount of generators.

Comment: You can also just capture the free variable in the call to filter, `picker = filter(lambda x, v=v: x%v !=0, picker)`

Comment: Yeah, do it any way you like.  I thought using a local function makes the point clearer than this `v=v` which needs more explaining.  But sure, that would work also.

Comment: @thebjorn Thanks! That is the core of my problem - due to lexical scoping and how closures work in python, the value `v` is updated in the "old" filters, too.